# How to hide directory in url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, xampp

Currently I can call my app (PHP) with the following URL:

```
http://localhost/app/public/index.html
```

Is there some way to hide the `public` in the url, so I can access the app just with `http://localhost/app/index.html`?

With the .htaccess file it should be possible. I am using XAMPP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: why can you just save the .html file in /app folder (ps, for it to run php code the extention must be .php)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mod_rewrite for this. Instead, just set your web server's configuration such that the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is pointing to `public` and not a directory above it. This will have the desired effect as well as preventing your server from handing out things that aren't intended to be public.

Edit: Note, this requires name-based virtual hosting and will require you do effectively dedicate a domain name to your app, but that's not a big deal.